# WSO2 GREG 4.6.0. Users other than admin cannot create services when servicePath is changed

Tags: service, registry, wso2, soa

I am working with WSO2 Greg 4.6.0 to build a service registry for my enterprise.
If I move the service path from trunk to other path by modifying the `servicePath`value in `registry.xml` like below, users other than admin cannot create services anymore.

```
<staticConfiguration>
    <versioningProperties>true</versioningProperties>
    <versioningComments>true</versioningComments>
    <versioningTags>true</versioningTags>
    <versioningRatings>true</versioningRatings>
    <servicePath>/myenterprise/services/</servicePath>
</staticConfiguration>
```

I have the following error message:

> Failed to add new resource. User toto does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/myenterprise/services.

The problem remains even if I give full permissions to the user.

Did I miss something to configure?

Thanks in advance for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permission to '`toto`' user belonging role to read and write to `/myenterprise/services/` collection.

Please refer [Managing Role Permissions](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Managing+Role+Permissions) doc.